# Open UTF-8 csv files by double-clicking in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, csv, utf-8, double-click

I want to open UTF-8 coded csv- or text-files directly in Excel 2016 or later.
Of course I am aware of the import option, but I want to do this with a simple double-click.

Problem is that this way Excel will not show all UTF-8 characters - e.g. Cyrillic characters - correctly.

My OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

The ways to achieve this that I can see are:

- Prepend a
  [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
  at the beginning of the file, preferably when the CSV file is created.
  The UTF-8 BOM is the hexadecimal byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`.
- For advanced users : Add a VBA macro to open the file as UTF-8
  with the parameter `Origin:=65001` for UTF-8.

You will find more details and flavors of the above in the post
[Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)

Comment: Thanks!

UTF-8 with BOM is no real option. All files come as UTF-8…

Regarding a macro, could you please explain what exactly you mean. As I said, I want to open existing UTF-8 files in Excel by double-clicking on them.

I found this: [link] (https://superuser.com/questions/1212741/microsoft-excel-utf-8-encoding-without-importing/1704699#1704699)

But the script won't open Excel (PS set to unrestricted, also running script in PS won't open Excel)
Can you help?

Comment: And the [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically) doesn't help me either.

I know those method of importing csv files. But that's too time consuming working with quite a number of csv files every day:

Double-Click for me is the only option :-(

Comment: The only double-click method I can see is to create a `.bat` file that copies the CSV, adding the UTF-8 BOM at its beginning and then open the file with Excel. Set this `.bat` as the handler of `.csv` files. Thus the double-click will open the copy.