# Removing 3D Builder in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, batch-file, bloatware

I type this in PowerShell running as administrator to remove 3D Builder:

```
C:\Windows\System32>get-appxpackage *3dbuilder* | remove-appxpackage
```

It works fine, but how can I write the line in a Batch file to do the same thing?

Comment: Enable .PS1 files on the PC (not on by default) and save that line in a PS1 script. See https://superuser.com/questions/106360/how-to-enable-execution-of-powershell-scripts

Comment: Another way is to add quote the whole command and add `Powershell` before it. Then save it as batch file

Comment: This link would be helpful for you: Removing Built-in apps from Windows 10 WIM-File with Powershell - Version 1.3 https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Removing-Built-in-apps-65dc387b

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this will not work is that a PowerShell script is very different from a batch file both in terms of its contents AND the way windows (by default) will handle it.

For Example - if you save `Write-Host $ENV:COMPUTERNAME` into a PowerShell (.ps1) file and double click it - it wil most likely open in Notepad!

If you really want to have this single line PowerShell command into a batch file - you want something like `powershell.exe -command "get-appxpackage *3dbuilder* | remove-appxpackage"` saved inside your batch file.  You should then be able to right click and "run as Administrator" on the batch file to get your desired effects.

Failing that - if you have a .ps1 PowerShell script - you can call it from a batch file using `PowerShell.exe -File C:\Folder\script.ps1` and run it from an administrative command line.

Alternatively, you will need to open PowerShell (or ISE) as an administrator and execute the script (`& C:\Folder\file.ps1`)

Lastly - you can use the `-verb RunAs` switch to try and force elevation if needed when calling PowerShell.exe or you can use the following block of script inside your script to cause a session to elevate (with a UAC prompt if needed):

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {  

  $arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
   Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
   Break

}
###My Script Code Goes Here and will be executed if I am an administrator!
```

Side note - you could go down the horrible route of reconfiguring windows to open PowerShell scripts into PowerShell and/or add a windows context menu to run in powershell as an admin - but this is messy and dangerous to say the least.